# Terminology for multiply visiting walks of directed graphs

Tags: graphs, terminology

In phrasing an information model for consumption-optimized RDF-like data (full context at [1](https://github.com/core-wg/coral/pull/1#issuecomment-921861748) for the curious), I'm looking for any established term for *X* as used here:

> Given is a directed rooted graph. An *X* is a (finite) sequence of edges, which go down the tree and then jump up again to a point where they've been just before.

In less precise and more illustrative words, an *X* is a line you can draw by going along edges; you may backtrack whenever you want, but usually can't go down the same path again. When you enter a node a second time (necessarily through a different path leading in), you switch over to a transparent overlay sheet as to keep things apart.

Note that this is looking for a descriptive term for that sequence (like "directed graph" is a term for an unordered set of nodes and edges), not for an algorithm producing any of these. (There will be programs producing such *X*, but what I'm looking for is to properly describe these programs' outputs, not the programs themselves).

It's tempting to say that *X* is a (somewhat ordered) tree, but for each time a node is entered, any or all of downstream "tree" can be traversed, possibly even in a different order. It's also not a walk (because we're jumping back up) or a traversal (because we access multiple times).

For example, for this digraph (which happens to be acyclic, but that's not a requirement):

[image: digraph { A -> B -> C -> E2 -> F; C -> E1; A -> Z -> C; }]

legal *X* would be:

- `A -> B -> C -> E2 -> F; C -> E1; A -> Z -> C` (which is taking all only once from left to right)
- `A -> B -> C -> E2 -> F; C -> E1; A -> Z -> C -> E2 -> F; C -> E1` (which is duplicating the whole walk down of C when C is reached again), or even
- `A -> B -> C -> E2 -> F; A -> Z -> C -> E1` (which expresses part of what's under C when coming from B, and another part when coming from Z)

Examples of non-*X*s are (which would also happen to be incomplete in covering the graph, but non-X examples that do cover the graph would be very unwieldly):

- `A -> B -> C -> C2; Z -> C` (because it jumps across without having been to Z before)
- `A -> B -> C -> E2; B -> C` (because it does `B -> C` again without having come into B for a second time)
- `A -> Z -> C -> E2; A -> B -> C -> E1; E2 -> F` (because while it has been at E2, it (so far, legally) backtracked to the branch through B (legal so far) but then jumped to E2 without having been there on the current leg)

(These could all be visualized nicely if I was any better in graphviz...)

Things *X* is not:

- A tree spanning the graph: Because it can come back on itself.
- An ordered list of edges (where only orderings are valid): Because if one has visited some node multiple times and not yet left it, an edge leaving it in the list does not indicate which visitation is being left.
- A traversal of the graph: Just provides a list (ie. see above).

Is there an established name for this structure *X*?

---

The actual graph we're considering is a multigraph with non-unique labels for edges, but that's likely immaterial to the question.

Comment: It's unclear, how the traverse algorithm should decide where to go next. For example, your variants #1 and #2 differ by what happens at node 'C' - the #1 stops, but the #2 continues to go to the node 'E2' and so on. Please formalize this decision, and may be, you'll need a variable (or variables), corresponding to each node.

Comment: (It might help to present an excluded sequence like $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow E1; Z$). Does every jump need to start from a leaf? Your first example visits `C` twice. `DAGs` in the title does not fit `acyclic [is] not a requirement` in the post body.

Comment: Thanks, updated: It's not about any algorithm but the output of algorithms. Negative examples added and title fixed. Jumps are more like backtracks.

Comment: I've added notes on what *X* is not. This is putting me on a path to explore whether it might be a good idea to plainly rule out recursion, and indeed treat everything as an ordered list of edges.